# Auto detecting the language of user

Tags: php, ip-address, region

Can i get the region code and country code from the ip address and is there any way to get the users language by passing the region and country code?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get the browser language but if you want to get the language based on the region through IP address, you have to use an API provided by a good IP Geo location tool. Some of them are mentioned in this thread: [Good Geolocation API by IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331627/good-geolocation-api-by-ip). But again, for some users like travellers etc., language has nothing to do with the location. So in my opinion its much better to check the browser headers for the preferred languages.